# How to use API in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, api, razorpay

I would like to connect one Razorpay Payment API with WordPress, API has authentication token using username and password.

is there any builtin functionality available in WordPress to make a call and handle response?

Comment: There is a plugin available for WooCommerce https://wordpress.org/plugins/woo-razorpay/. 

However, if you want to make custom calls using a builtin Wordpress function, you can make use of Requests Class. https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/requests/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you can use `wp_remote_get()`

for example

```
wp_remote_get( 'http://www.example.com/index.php?action=foo', array( 'timeout' => 120, 'httpversion' => '1.1' ) );
```

you can also control all request parameters like headers and body data.

**Default Usage**

```
global $wp_version;
$args = array(
    'timeout'     => 5,
    'redirection' => 5,
    'httpversion' => '1.0',
    'user-agent'  => 'WordPress/' . $wp_version . '; ' . home_url(),
    'blocking'    => true,
    'headers'     => array(),
    'cookies'     => array(),
    'body'        => null,
    'compress'    => false,
    'decompress'  => true,
    'sslverify'   => true,
    'stream'      => false,
    'filename'    => null
);
```

Reference : [More info](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_remote_get)

Comment: How to pass username and password fields in wp_remote_get()?

Comment: you can pass it via headers or body as an element according to their API request.

Comment: you can make the request like this `api:secret@api.razorpay.com`